# Prevent JS Keypress Event from Bubbling up

Tags: javascript, lightning

In my custom lightning component if do have some nested sub-components.
One contains a rather large picklist.
Users tend to click the picklist and start typing the first letters for the item they're looking for, e.g. if they're looking for an item "Power Generator", they type "Power".

In Firefox however as soon as a user types the letter "e" the "Edit Record" dialog opens. This is because of the newly introduced keyboard shortcuts for lightning experience.

My question now is: How do I suppress the appearance of that dialog?
I have unsuccessfully tried to do this in my root component:

```
<aura:component>
<div onkeypress="{!c.onKeyPress}">
<!-- Content and nested components -->
</div>
</aura:component>
```

And in my controller I did this, which - you might have guessed - did not suppress the dialog:

```
onKeyPress: function (component, event, helper)
{
    // I tried both variants - neither worked...
    //event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // UPDATE: Also tried this, does not work either
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

**Update 2:** The onKeyPress handler *is* executed, it's the event methods that have no effect.

Any insights on how to suppress the dialog is highly appreciated!

Comment: did you try event.preventdefault();?

Comment: Just tried it - does not work either.

Comment: Can you share some more code so that we can try the same and debug the issue?

Comment: I know that you have to suppress the event in the CAPTURE phase for lightning events - however, this looks more like a standard html event, so I'm not sure in this case. To handle the event in the capture phase, add an `<aura:handler> for this event, with `phase="capture"`

Comment: @CasparHarmer: I don't know if this is a Lightning Event - could be. Do you happen to know what event i would have to add a handler for?